# _Why does this left join not give me an results?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 3 tables as shown below (each table has additional columns which don't affect the query):

Courses

```
+-----------+
| course_id |
+-----------+
| 37        |
+-----------+
```

Course_enrollment

```
+-----------+--------+
| course_id | user_id|
+-----------+--------+
| 37        |   91   |
| 37        |   89   | 
+-----------+--------+
```

Completed_courses

```
+-----------+--------------+
| course_id | user_id      |
+-----------+--------------+
| 37        | 89           |
+-----------+--------------+
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting an empty result in the following query:

```
SELECT 
    courses.*, completed_courses.*, course_enrollment.* 
FROM 
    courses
INNER JOIN 
    course_enrollment ON courses.course_id = course_enrollment.course_id
LEFT JOIN 
    completed_courses ON (course_enrollment.course_id = completed_courses.course_id)
WHERE 
    course_enrollment.user_id = '91'
    AND completed_courses.course_id IS NULL
```

Since I'm using a `LEFT JOIN` and checking whether completed_courses.course_id IS NULL, shouldn't I get one result?

Comment: `courses.course_id` ? ( after the `INNER JOIN` line ) ... There is only an `id` column in the `Courses` table

Comment: try AND completed_courses.user_id IS NULL instead of AND completed_courses.course_id IS NULL

Comment: @engineer fixed the typo...

Comment: @Webstser still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are joining `completed_courses` only on the course id.  That join also needs `user_id`.

I think you intend:

```
SELECT c.*, cc.*, ce.* 
FROM courses c INNER JOIN
     course_enrollment ce
     ON c.course_id = ce.course_id LEFT JOIN 
     completed_courses cc
     ON ce.course_id = cc.course_id AND
        ce.user_id = cc.user_id
WHERE ce.user_id = '91' AND
      cc.course_id IS NULL ;
```

Notice that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Can you please clarify your line: ce.user_id = ce.user_id?

Comment: It's a typo. He ment `ce.user_id = cc.user_id`

Comment: That did it!  However, I'm still not seeing why the original query didn't work as well. What's the difference in what I'm querying for once I add in the user_id piece within the ON statement?  I would have thought that my  original WHERE statement took care of the user_id...

Comment: A row from `course_enrollment ` is the same as in `completed_courses ` if both the `course_id` and `user_id` are the same, meaning the join should be made by both columns

Comment: OK!  That makes sense.  In other words, in my query, I was looking at courses from completed_courses that were not necessarily relevant to the particular user.

Comment: @Eric . . . Yes, exactly.